# Thread synchronisation on files WIN32 API

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io

I am developing a Client-Server app in Win32 API and I'm trying to remove a record from a login.txt file, where I store all my logged users. The problem is that the file that I'm using doesn't get deleted, and the temporary file doesn't get renamed (They do 2-3 times, but after several logouts it fails).

My code for that is:

```
EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection2);

    TCHAR tmpString[256];
    FILE *tmp = NULL;

    tmp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Liviu\\Desktop\\temporaryFile.txt", "w");

    if (!tmp)
    {
        printf("Temporary file could not open");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }

    TCHAR searchString[20];

    // Removes the possibility of having the ThreadId = password
    sprintf(searchString, "%s%d", ",", GetCurrentThreadId());

    // Paste all the lines execept the specified record to the tmp file
    while (fgets(tmpString, 255, loginFile))
    {
        if (!strstr(tmpString, searchString))
        {
            fputs(tmpString, tmp);
        }
    }

    fclose(tmp);
    fclose(loginFile);

    // I have put "while" here just to make sure this actually works, but it doesn't
    while (remove("C:\\Users\\Liviu\\Desktop\\login.txt") != 0)
        ;

    while (rename("C:\\Users\\Liviu\\Desktop\\temporaryFile.txt", "C:\\Users\\Liviu\\Desktop\\login.txt") != 0)
        ;

    LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection2);
```

How can I make this work ? I think it's about the thread synchronisation, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `"C:\..\..\in.txt"` is two directories up from the root directory of drive c:, this doesn't look right.

Comment: and what is  `GetLastError()` ?

Comment: Wondering if this is something simple like building the project using unicode text, but using ansi text call for CreateFile().

Comment: also you all time use different options - `OPEN_EXISTING`, `CREATE_NEW`, `CREATE_ALWAYS`. may be *\??\c:\in.txt* simply not exist

Comment: Why not just use [`CopyFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851.aspx) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not show the actual paths you are passing to `CreateFile()`, or the error code that `GetLastError()` is reporting, so noone can help you understand why it is failing.

But, even if `CreateFile()` were working, you are passing invalid parameters to `ReadFile()` and `WriteFile()`, so your code would still fail to copy data from one file to the other.  In fact, the code is very likely to just crash altogether and terminate.

Try something more like this instead:

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    int exitCode = 1;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("not enough arguments!"));
        goto done;
    }

    _tprintf(_T("%s\n%s\n"), argv[1], argv[2]);

    HANDLE hFile1 = CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);
    if (hFile1 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Cant open File 1, Error: %d\n"), GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

    HANDLE hFile2 = CreateFile(argv[2], GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);
    if (hFile2 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Cant open File 2, Error: %d\n"), GetLastError());
        goto cleanup1;
    }

    BYTE a[100];
    BYTE *ptr;
    DWORD bytesRead;
    DWORD bytesWritten;

    do
    {
        if (!ReadFile(hFile1, a, sizeof(a), &bytesRead, NULL))
        {
            _tprintf(_T("Cant read from File 1, Error: %d\n"), GetLastError());
            goto cleanup;
        }

        if (bytesRead == 0)
            break;

        ptr = a;
        do
        {
            if (!WriteFile(hFile2, ptr, bytesRead, &bytesWritten, NULL))
            {
                _tprintf(_T("Cant write to File 2, Error: %d\n"), GetLastError());
                goto cleanup;
            }
            ptr += bytesWritten;
            bytesRead -= bytesWritten;
        }
        while (bytesRead != 0);
    }
    while (true);

    _tprintf(_T("Finished\n"));
    exitCode = 0;

cleanup:
    CloseHandle(hFile2);
cleanup1:
    CloseHandle(hFile1);

done:
    system("pause");
    return exitCode;
}
```

That being said, your code is basically just duplicating what [`CopyFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851.aspx) already does, so you might consider using that instead:

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    int exitCode = 1;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("not enough arguments!"));
        goto done;
    }

    _tprintf(_T("%s\n%s\n"), argv[1], argv[2]);

    if (!CopyFile(argv[1], argv[2], FALSE))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Cant copy File, Error: %d\n"), GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

    _tprintf(_T("Finished\n"));
    exitCode = 0;

done:
    system("pause");
    return exitCode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me a good example. I have put my paths in Visual studio -> project properties -> Command Arguments like this: "C:\Users\Liviu\Desktop\in.txt" "C:\Users\Liviu\Desktop\out.txt" Is there any problem ? GetLastError() shows code 0.

Comment: @Liviu those paths look fine. And `GetLastError()` is only meaningful in this situation when something fails, and it can't return 0 in that case unless you do something to reset it. That is not true in my examples. So  what EXACTLY is your code outputting, and from where?

Comment: When I run it, on the screen is printed hFile1 is not ok 0.  A file with unreadable characters is created and with no content in it.

Comment: @Liviu: `GetLastError()` is returning 0 because you are preceding it with a call to `printf()` that is likely resetting it back to 0, losing the error code from `CreateFile()`. When using `GetLastError()`, you need to call it *immediately* after the failed function, before calling anything else that might reset it.

Comment: @Liviu: in the code you originally showed, you are not exiting the program immediately if either `CreateFile()` fails. So you end up trying to read from an unopened input file, and have nothing to write to the output file.  And like I said earlier, you are passing invalid parameter values to `ReadFile()` and `WriteFile()` anyway (and you are not doing any error handling on them at all), so you could even end up writing garbage to File 2.  Assuming your code doesn't just crash outright. The code in my answer addresses all of these problems.  Did you even try my code yet?

Comment: Yes, it works. I was just wondering why mine wasn't working (after I have change the ReadFile and WriteFile functions). Didn't know calling another function would reset GetLastError(). Thank you !

Answer (score -2):

If your error is that char * cannot be converted to wchar_t const * use CreateFileA instead of CreateFile for the argv case, or switch to using int wmain(int, wchar_t * argv[]) instead of int main(int, char *[])

Comment: The OP is getting a runtime error, not a compile-time error. The code would not even compile if there were a data type mismatch

Comment: you shouldn't down-vote so quickly.  I just tried changing the main to wmain and hey presto it worked!  Until then it was working on only the first character passed to the main argv